# Decreasing amortized time complexity of finding first set bit

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

The find first set bit algorithm simply scans the bit array to find the first set bit which is in fact  a basic sequential search algorithm.

Supposing we have access to operations that set and clear the bits of the array, is it possible to decrease the amortized complexity with following requirements:

- Additional memory can be used but it should be constant, O(1).
- The bit array cannot be sorted or changed.

As an example, one simple optimization might be to have an extra integer holding the last cleared bit index. Then the subsequent search will just return that, in O(1) time. But it seems to me that this does not affect the amortized running time at all, since this simple improvement cannot define any bounds for the worst-case of the algorithm. But a set of improvements like these might decrease the amortized time complexity? Or not?

Regards,

Comment: In the worst case, all the bits are set so you cannot do better than a sequential search *in the worst case*. Of course there may be algorithms which do better in the average case.

Comment: `space complexity shall not be changed` != `additional memory can be used but it should be constant O(1)`. the bitset is O(n) memory, so any data structure that is also O(n) [and you have finite number of those data structures of course] is valid, since it won't change the memory complexity. So which one is it? O(1) space complexity? or same space complexity [O(n)] ?

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. What I mean by space complexity shall not be changed is that, Only O(1) space is allowed be used to optimize/improve the algorithm but not O(N). That is because memory efficiency is the most important thing for our use case. However, if you can find a way to decrease amortized time with using O(N) space(of course, with additional N bits, not any other data structure:)), I would like to hear that, too.

Comment: What % of bits do you expect to be set?  I get the impression they're very sparse - yes?

Comment: In fact, not sure, the bitset is used to flag the free/unfree chunks of memory in a slab memory allocator. So, I think we can say the input is random.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to knock together a simple binary search using bit operators, but of course the Stanford Bit twiddling hacks page has that: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightBinSearch. This gives O(log n) for n bit representations. It doesn't use bit setting/clearing operations, just tests. I assume this is allowable?

In that category (Zeros on right), there are several other approaches you might like.

Comment: I am aware of the page. Unfortunately, the bit array I mentioned in the question can have a dynamic size and so the runtime complexity depends on the number of bits. However, if you can adapt that algorithm to a dynamic sized bit array, then we are ok.